# $\{ a+\sqrt2 b \mid a,b \text{ are rational numbers}\}$ is closed under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

> Prove $H=\{ a+\sqrt2 b \mid a,b \text{ are rational numbers}\}$ is closed under multiplication.

All I have to prove is that if we multiple two elements of $H,$ then again we can write it in $a+\sqrt2 b$ form for $a,b$ rational. Right?

But $(a+\sqrt2 b)\cdot (a-\sqrt2 b)= a^2-2b^2.$
Then does it belong to $H$ or not, since I can’t write it in $a+\sqrt2 b$ form?

Comment: $a^2 - 2b^2$ is a rational number and it is already of the form $x + y\sqrt{2}$ where $x = a^2 - 2b^2$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: $a^2-2b^2$ is of the form $p+q\sqrt{2}$ when you let $q=0$

Comment: Do not confuse the intention of the letters $a$ and $b$ in the above.  Reworded, any number which could be written as some rational number plus a rational multiple of $\sqrt{2}$ multiplied by another number which is also some rational number plus some rational multiple of $\sqrt{2}$ can be written as some rational number plus some rational multiple of $2$.  Note that $0$ is a rational number and we have for instance $(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})=\underbrace{(a-2b^2)}_{\in\Bbb Q} + \underbrace{0}_{\in\Bbb Q}\sqrt{2}$

Comment: So... you are tasked with proving that given some rationals $a,b,c,d$ then there exist rationals $p,q$ such that $(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2}) = p+q\sqrt{2}$.... that is to say, your set is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Yeah yeah correct

Answer (score 4):

Let $a+\sqrt{2}b, c+\sqrt{2}d \in H.$ You need to show $(a+\sqrt{2}b)(c+\sqrt{2}d) \in H.$ Consider $$(a+\sqrt{2}b)(c+\sqrt{2}d)=(ac+2bd)+\sqrt{2}(ad+bc).$$ Since $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q},$ therefore $ac+2bd,ad+bc\in \mathbb{Q}.$ Hence $(a+\sqrt{2}b)(c+\sqrt{2}d) \in H.$

**Edit:** In your example, $a-2b^2=a-2b^2+\sqrt{2} \ (0)\in H.$